# Implementing elearing application using spring boot and angular

Tags: jquery, angular, xml, hibernate, mysql-workbench

In java using spring boot and angular js ,how to store scorm package content and play using scorm content player .I don't have any idea.Only i have extracted scorm package and read imsmanifest.xml .But , next what to do? Can anyone guide or tell steps? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few key areas to deal with -

1. **SCORM Runtime APIs** (javascript) for either SCORM 1.2 or SCORM 2004.  These are based on hundreds of pages of white papers from ADL.  You can hack something together, but I'll be straight here, it takes a solid 12-24 months to do it right from scratch.  You're essentially building a API off white papers.
2. You have a **CMI Object** to manage.  This is the student attempt.  All things in SCORM are a string, and the Runtime API manages the legality of those strings.  LMS is responsible for preparing a clean student attempt, and preserving an attempt when the student suspends their session.  This is another vast area with thresholds (success, completion), timeouts and types that has to be managed.

Angular will need to have TypeScript satisfied to expose global APIs like this, since this is what your SCO typically ran in a IFRAME, window or tab, or popup will connect to.

You'll want to maintain a sequence of preparing the student attempt (clean or prior), then load the SCO, allow it to connect to your Runtime API based on that imsmanifest.xml schema version (SCORM 1.2 or 2004), all the student to interact with the content, save the student attempt based on events you can set up.

### Simple SCORM 2004 / 1.2 terms

- Initialize / LMSInitialize - SCO will call this, assets won't
- GetValue / LMSGetValue - data retrieved by SCO (cmi.x)
- SetValue / LMSSetValue - data set by SCO (cmi.x, 'value')
- Commit / LMSCommit - store student data to your backend
- Terminate / LMSTerminate - session over, no further interaction with SCORM

You can buy your way out of this, but you'd need to google around for SCORM options and even this site has great resources prior.  Just use the search term SCORM, switch to oldest or newest and review many of the questions already asked before.  SCORM's been around for almost 20 years now so there is no shortage on this subject.

I would not discourage anyone wanting to code this up from scratch though.  I've done it, and it's rewarding when you get it working.

Good Luck